# How to reserve the size for the container?

Tags: docker

I would like to use this docker file https://github.com/filak-sap/sap-nw-abap-docker to install the container.

On the github website under the installation construction, it says:

```
Set up docker on your instance

docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=60G
```

When I typed it into the terminal, the output is:

```
docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=60G
unknown flag: --storage-opt
See 'docker --help'.

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

`--storage-opt` is an option of `dockerd` ([Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)) and not `docker` (Docker client) so you can only use this when starting docker with dockerd. So you have to stop the docker daemon and then you can restart it with `dockerd --storage-opt dm.basesize=60G`

The alternative is to put this manually into the [daemon.json](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/) which is located at `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (on linux systems).

This would look like:

```
{
        "storage-opts": [ "dm.basesize=60G" ]
}
```